# Текст в динамически созданных кнопках html

Tags: javascript, html, input

Есть код генерирующий `input`, я решил в этих `input` разместить текст, но что-то пошло не так. Ниже прикрепляю код в html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>UNBE</title>

    <script src="/eel.js"></script>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/unbe.png">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function createContentInScroll(quantityBr, whereToInsertNode) {
          for (let i = 0; i <= quantityBr; i++) {
            const textContentInput = document.createElement('input');
            textContentInput.type = `text`;
            textContentInput.id = `content${i}`;
            textContentInput.title = `Введите текстовое содержание строки отыгровки.`;
            textContentInput.textContent = `Задержка (мс)`;
            whereToInsertNode.append(textContentInput);
            const brNode = document.createElement('br');
            whereToInsertNode.append(brNode);
          }
        }
    </script>

    <div id="editorScroll">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            createContentInScroll(30, editorScroll)
        </script>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут ошибочка, замени `textContentInput.textContent =` Задержка (мс)`;`
на `textContentInput.value =` Задержка (мс)`;`

Для доступа к инпуту нужен `value`